# Emit value only if user is offline for specified time

Tags: typescript, rxjs

From the backend I got a stream where a list of active userIds are emitted. In my angular service I need to create an observable and emit a value when there is a user who is offline let's say for 5s.

My service so far:

```
public constructor(private userService: UserService) {
    const userGetOffline = userService.activeUserIds$
        .pipe(
        pairwise(),
            map(([prev, curr]) => {
                let offlineCount = 0;
                prev.forEach(prevItem => {
                    if (!curr.includes(prevItem)) {
                        offlineCount++;
                    }
                });

                return offlineCount > 0;
            }),
            filter(offline => offline),
            tap(_ => console.log("User get offline"))
        );

    const userGetOnline = userService.activeUserIds$
        .pipe(
        pairwise(),
            map(([prev, curr]) => {
                let onlineCount = 0;
                curr.forEach(currItem => {
                    if (!prev.includes(currItem)) {
                        onlineCount++;
                    }
                });

                return onlineCount > 0;
            }),
            filter(online => online),
            tap(_ => console.log("User get offline"))
        );
}
```

And now I'm stuck. I can create an observable when some user/s get online / offline, but I can't come up with idea how to combine them together and emit only when the user is in offline state for 5s. I know I will need debounceTime but how to combine them, I have no idea.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ccnokes/bd5b975dab213bb60b877e49754dd675#gistcomment-3192446

Comment: Why do you need to combine both streams? Don't you care only about offline users? And how often are you getting emissions from the server?

Comment: I'd recommend creating some [marble diagrams](https://rxmarbles.com/) of how you expect the input/output to look.